# Object conversion in android

Tags: android, ajax, json

> I have one server URL, when i send request to server URL, 
>   Get data in Ajax Servlet format.
>   so i want to store this responded data in json object format in mobile side.
>   How is it possible Please guide me
>   The responded data have multiple city name

Comment: What is `Ajax Servlet format`?

Comment: <response>
    <AIRPORTS>
    <AIRPORT id="BOM/Mumbai,India(BOM)" name="Mumbai,India(BOM)"/>
    <AIRPORT id="MUM/Mumias,Kenya(MUM)" name="Mumias,Kenya(MUM)"/>
    </AIRPORTS>
    </response>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is xml format. So you have to convert xml to json.
You can use  [java json](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java/java-json.jar.zip) library to do it.
It provides api to do so.
`JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(yourXmlString);`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html i refer this link, i got tag name but i need tag contain i.e city name help me out

Comment: using getText() not get the xml item i.e city name so which method i have to use syam-kumar-s

Comment: You can use `parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name")`. @kirti

Comment: Thanks Sir I got result

Comment: Sir If i Want to save this city name in list how it possible  List<String> var = new ArrayList<String>(); var.add("Lars"); // Loop over it and print the result to the console
        for (String s : var) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

Comment: try this code for creating a list of airport names.

`List<String>  var = new ArrayList<String>();   
   int eventType = parser.getEventType();  
   while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {  
   if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {  
               String value = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");  
      if(value!=null && !value.isEmpty()){  
    var.add(value);  
      }  
   }     
   eventType = xpp.next();  
   }  `

Comment: i defined => HashMap<String, String> CityWithCode = new HashMap<String, String>(); and store the city code and city name in hash map like this way => CityWithCode.put(id, value); so retrieve the data from hash map = > for (HashMap map: CityWithCode) {
    String value = map.get(id); 
}   Is It right ?????

Comment: Yes. You can use a HashMap to keepyour data. But what is your question??